# Есть ли ошибка во фразе "Вашей задачей является привлечь"?

Tags: синтаксис

Мне кажется, что "привлечь" не может являться задачей. "Привлечение" — ещё куда ни шло. "Ваша задача — привлечь" также нормальный вариант. Но можно ли сказать так, как в примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Привлечь** внимание противника **является** вашей основной **задачей**.
Подлежащее - инфинитив, полузнаменательная связка "является" и именная часть в форме Т.п.

Подобные конструкции с инфинитивом встречаются в литературе, и в некоторых случаях они более лаконичны и выразительны, чем варианты с отглагольным существительным.

**Из Интернета**

(1) Тогда **создать** возможно благоприятные общегигиенические условия в таких классных комнатах **является задачей** хороших отопительных и вентиляционных устройств при умеренной эксплуатации их. [Ф. Ф. Эрисман. Школьная гигиена (1871-1908)]

(2) Я отвечал, что разумеется, нашим заветнейшим **желанием является  привлечь** армию к переходу на сторону народа; если возможно целиком, с офицерами во главе; это лучшее, о чем только можно мечтать. [В. М. Чернов. Перед бурей. Воспоминания (1953)]

(3)Энциклика констатирует, что модернизм представляет серьезную опасность для церкви, и **обязанностью** папы **является принять** против этого меры. [неизвестный. Вести (1907.09.18) // «Русское слово», 1907]

(4)Если у посетителя проснулся интерес, следующим логичным позывом будет желание приобрести товар. Вашей **задачей является сформулировать** желание и **мотивировать** пользователя дополнительной информацией, подчеркивающий полезные свойства продукции.

Answer (score 1):

```
  "привлечь" не может являться задачей
```

Почему не может? Может.Вариант разговорный,с канцелярским оттенком, но не ошибка, не просторечие."Привлечь как можно больше посетителей является нашей задачей".

Подлежащее вполне может быть выражено инфинитивом.